# Are fingerprint scanners easy to bypass?

Tags: authentication, biometrics

Thinking about adding a fingerprint based authentication layer, but then I recalled the [MythBusters beat fingerprint security system episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAfAVGES-Yc) -- is this a common issue, and if not, how do you tell if a fingerprint authentication system is easy or hard to bypass?

Comment: One important point is that even if they work correctly, they can only serve as local and not as remote identification.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Not following you, if the finger is scanned remotely or local how does that effect it working correctly?

Comment: The issue is that the attacker must not have control over the scanner itself. So it can't be used for home banking or similar remote applications where the defender can't prevent the attacker from tampering with the scanner or using his own scanner.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I don't think you are correct in your assumption. See http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/67.pdf for example.

Comment: @mikeazo I don't believe there is any way around the fact that biometric data behaves like a single, unchangeable password. And assuming that a fingerprint stays secret is pretty naive too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, The research area is still young, but check this paper out: http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/086.pdf Here is a relevant quote "We emphasize that the biometric measurement for an individual need not be kept secret. Indeed, it is not if it is used as a public key." I'm not saying that it is ready for prime-time, but cool stuff is being done.

Comment: @mikeazo: Any reason you're not posting an answer, appears that you're aware of a lot of information on the subject.

Comment: @blunders, honestly I don't know much about the state of current commercial products. I've read some of the newer research, but am not sure if it is even being applied into existing products. That said, I'll try to throw together an answer about the research aspects.

Comment: When the iPhone 5S came to market with a fingerprint scanner for user authentication, the Chaos Computer Club in Germany bet that they could hack it with an artificial fingerprint in a few weeks. They hacked it in a day.

Comment: "... thinking about adding a fingerprint based authentication layer..." - how does a person change their fingerprint once the fingerprint database is breached? This has the same downside as the "public information as security questions", like "what's your mother's maiden name". How does you mom change her maiden name after the breach?

Comment: All you have to know is electrical engineering... Hardware and software; take notes down while you balance it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fingerprints can be viewed as a fuzzy source of data. Given the same finger, a reader might never read exactly the same print. That is why most readers require the user to scan a finger multiple times during the registration phase.

During the authentication phase, the system tries to determine if the scan it just acquired is "close enough" to the trained data to allow access. This leads to two problems.

1. Remote authentication
2. Keeping biometric private

**Remote Authentication**

Assume I keep my biometric private (we'll deal with that problem later). Can I give another party enough information to correctly authenticate me without requiring them to store enough information to impersonate me (i.e., if someone steals the database, I don't want them to be able to impersonate me)?

It turns out you can. The functions needed are called [secure sketches and fuzzy extractors](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/papers/fuzzy.pdf). A secure sketch (SS) is given some data (w) and returns string (s) in other words SS(w)=s. A secure sketch also has a recovery function (Rec). Rec takes as input w' (a noisy copy of w) and s. If w' is sufficiently close to w (where closeness is measured by some distance metric such as hamming distance), then Rec(w',s)=w. Now the server and I share a secret value (namely w) which we can each prove knowledge of to authenticate each other (mutual authentication).

The cool thing about this is that even if someone steals s, they won't be able to impersonate me. There are a few problems with this, however. What if the attacker modifies the copy of s that the server is storing. Could they do that in such a way that w is leaked? In the original work, there were no guarantees that this couldn't happen. Later research, however, removed this restriction by developing what is called a [robust secure sketch](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/67.pdf), which is secure even in the presence of an active adversary (i.e., an adversarial controlled channel).

**Keeping biometric private**

The above ideas all assumed that w (and w') were kept private. This is probably not a good assumption as seen on [MythBusters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAfAVGES-Yc). So, researchers went back to the drawing board and said "Hey what if my fingerprint was my public key" and thus [Fuzzy Identity-Based Encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/086.pdf) (FIBE) was born.

Closely related to this is Identity Based Encryption, where my identity (e.g., email address) is my public key. Someone uses my email address to encrypt a message. I then prove to a third party that I own the email address, whereupon I am able to retrieve the corresponding private key and decrypt the encrypted message. It is important to note that the sender only needs some public information from the third party to enable her to encrypt messages to any identity. The receiver must at some point (either before or after the encrypted message is actually sent) retrieve his private key.

FIBE builds upon this idea for fuzzy identities. You read my fingerprint (w), I use w' to get my private key and as long as w and w' are close enough, I am able to retrieve the message you send to me (I still have to contact the third party at some time though). An authentication protocol could be built on this so that I need not keep my biometric private.

The major problem with this system (and IBE in general) is the requirement of a third party and the fact that that third party can impersonate me once they have seen a copy of my biometric. The latter problem can be removed by having multiple third parties who all contribute to the process. Thus, no single one can impersonate me. But, then I have to contact multiple people in order to encrypt or decrypt messages.

**Application**

I'm not sure if any commercial products implement these ideas. So, I cannot speak to commercially available products, but if you are not limited to commercially available products, you could implement these systems yourself and they would probably be pretty secure.

Comment: Note that the FIBE stuff is local, not remote: "The user must demonstrate ownership of the biometric under the supervision of a
well trained operator. If the operator is able to detect imitation attacks, for example playing the
recording of a voice,"

Comment: @CodeInChaos, That is true for the receiver. The receiver must demonstrate ownership of the biometric to the third party in order to receive her private key. If the user then caches the private key, they won't ever have to do it again. Good point though.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, yes, they are.  It's quite trivial, in fact, using a bit of scotch tape.

Fingerprints are actually more akin to *usernames* than *passwords*.  Fingerprints can be used to *identify* you, but not *authenticate* you.

The proper operation of a fingerprint reader in a computer operating system should be to *identify* the user and chose their username from the list, rather than replace a password.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental issue when using certain biometrics is the simple logic using something that the user leaves behind himself all over the place all day long as being quite unique. We can take pictures of faces, mimic sounds using a synthesizer and capture fingerprints quite easily. This brings us to the second major pitfall of biometrics.

Most biometric fingerprint scanners work like this: A device records a fingerprint and compares the ridges and valleys with a picture it already has. Certain points that may be considered unique are given a mathematical value, or *score*. If the score of this print is within an acceptable threshold - compared to the original score of the original print - access is granted.

This means that an attacker can simply raise the threshold margin to gain access. If usually two fingerprints have to be within 20 points to allow access, but an attacker gains access to the system and changes the threshold to 10000 points, then any fingerprint would allow him access to the system. In a business environment, most staff members wouldn't notice this, because the change affects false positives, not false negatives.

As far as I know, this trait is unique to biometrics.